# Lower bound for sum of integrals

Tags: integration, upper-lower-bounds

In the middle of a proof I encountered this type of expression:

$$\int_D Af^2+\int_{\partial D} Bf^2$$

where $D$ is a domain and $A$ and $B$ are not constants. I would like to find a lower bound of the form:

$$M\int_Df^2$$

for some $M$, but I am not sure whether this is possible in general. I thought of ignoring the second term and using Cauchy-Schwarz inequality on the first, but this gives me an upper instead of a lower bound. Any advice?

Comment: Without more assumptions, a lower bound with $M$ independent of $f$ is not possible. For example take $D = [0,1]$, $A(x) = -1/\sqrt{x}$, and $B = 0$. Then for a family of functions $f_n(x)$ equal to $1$ on $[0,1/n]$ and $0$ elsewhere, the expression you’re trying to bound is $-2/\sqrt{n}$, but $\int f^2 = 1/n$, which means we’d need $M \leq -2\sqrt{n}$ for all $n$. So $M$ would need to depend on $f$.

Comment: @kieransquared The key in your counterexample seems to be that A(x) is negative. What if both A and B were always positive, would it be possible to find M in that case?

Comment: If $B\geq 0$ and $A$ has a lower bound, then your estimate holds, but it should be possible to give examples where $M$ must be zero. For example, with $B$, $D$, and $f_n$ as before, let $A = x$, then you can show that for the desired bound to hold, we’d need $M \leq 1/(2n)$. (Assuming you want $M\geq 0$, since if $A,B>0$, you can pick any $M$ negative to get the desired bound)

Comment: @kieransquared Could you help me understand why the estimate holds? I had an intuition that it would be correct, but can't see how to prove it. Any hint would be appreciated, I'm curious to know.

Comment: Suppose $A(x)\geq M$ for all $x$, and $B\geq 0$. Then since $f^2 \geq 0$, $\int_D A f^2 + \int_{\partial D} Bf^2 \geq  \int_D A f^2 \geq M\int_D f^2$.

Comment: @kieransquared But why the last inequality? Since A depends on x, it can't be taken out of the integral. Is M some integral related to A? That's what I was initially trying to do, but I can't find a way to separate the integral as a product of integrals.

Comment: All I used was the fact that if $g(x) \geq f(x)$, then $\int g \geq \int f$. Note that M is a constant, it’s the lower bound for A.